# How to create side list showing current state in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xib

I've been looking for a UI control to show current state/screen of OSX app, in a side list, like PKG installers show, something like:
[image]

I need to be able to show 3 states: Passed, Active, Disabled (Haven't reached this state yet)

Any way I can achieve this in XIB?

Comment: Maybe this can be achieved by using a source list (it's an NSOutlineView, I think).

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I didn't see any way to add the bulleted list to a source list

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with Cocoa, but I doubt that these bullets are "real bullets". Each of these cells is being created from a "template" within the view controller (unless you're using bindings). Within the view controller you create cell objects and can decide which "bullet" you want to use in each cell.

Comment: Just use an NSTableView

Comment: How will that help me to create the 3 states bullet?